# Delphi XE5 - TWeBrowser Navigate PDF does not open

Tags: android, delphi, pdf

The code does not show any error. but it does not show the PDF either.

```
filename := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'Test.pdf');
WebBrowser1.Navigate('file:/' + filename);
```

More over, TWebBrowser is not opening any PDF links on an html page. I did this to test whether it open a PDF from a link on an HTML page.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try WebBrowser1.Navigate('file://' + filename);